# Appending a string when throwing an error in C++

Tags: c++, string, exception, try-catch, multi-catch

I'm sure this is something simple, but wasn't able to find any other posts clearly specifying this, though I'm sure there must be one buried somewhere.

In C++, when using a try catch block in the below manner, how can I append a string variable to the error message?

I get an unhandled exception when trying to do this. Is it something to do with what type is passed back? Appears to be returning a string versus a char*. if that is correct, would that cause the issue? How would I adjust for this? I tried adding an additional catch (const string my_msg), but that did not work, either.

```
string msg = "message";
try{
    if (...)
        throw "My error " + msg;
    }
catch (const char* my_msg){
    cerr << my_msg << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"My error " + msg` is an [operation that concatenates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) a `const char*` string and an `std::string`. This operation results in a temporary variable of type `std::string`. Therefore, the thrown variable must be caught with a catch clause of type `std::string`.

```
catch (const std::string& my_msg){
    cerr << my_msg << endl;
}
```

Still, it is better practice to have your exceptions derive from [`std::exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception). You don't need to create your own exception class though, as there is [`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) and its derivations, which provides useful classifications of common runtime exceptions.

There are many cases where you need to have a distinct type for your exceptions, often of  which may be project or domain specific. In C++11, making your own exception type is as easy as this

```
struct my_exception : std::runtime_error {
    using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;   // Inherit runtime_error's constructors
};
```

This uses C++11's [inheriting constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9979194/1619294).