# Can someone please explain the using BaseTypeX::BaseTypeX in this code?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, using, template-specialization

I have some code that is doing the following but I don't understand what the
 `using BaseTypeX::BaseTypeX` is actually doing in this code.  The rest of it I understand so please don't explain template specialization etc.

```
template<typename TReturn, typename... TArgs>
class ClassX<TReturn(TArgs...)> : public Internal::ClassXImpl<TReturn, TArgs...> {
public:

    using BaseTypeX = Internal::ClassXImpl<TReturn, TArgs...>;
    using BaseTypeX::BaseTypeX; // what is this doing exactly?

    inline ClassX() noexcept = default;

    // member function
    template<class TThis, class TFunc>
        inline ClassX(TThis* aThis, TFunc aFunc) {
            this->bind(aThis, aFunc);  // note bind is implemented in the ClassXImpl class
        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means you inherit all the constructors of `Internal::ClassXImpl<TReturn, TArgs...>`. A simpler example might illustrate this better:

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo(int);
  Foo(int, double);
  Foo(std::string);
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
  using Foo::Foo;
};

int main()
{
  Bar b1(42); // OK, Foo's constructors have been "inherited"
  Bar b2(42, 3.14); // OK too
  Bar b2("hello");  // OK
}
```

Without the `using Foo::Foo`, you would have to declare and define all the constructors in `Bar`, and call the respective `Foo` constructor in each one of them.

Comment: +1 oh wow I did not know that! Thanks so much. I will accept this as an answer once the time passes to allow me to

Answer (score 1):

It means template class `ClassX` inherits its base's constructors. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979194/what-is-constructor-inheritance) for a discussion on the topic.

Comment: +1 thanks this helps. the example in the other answer really solidified it for me as well.