# Inherit and overload default constructor

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, constructor

I've been searching for this and I'm amazed I haven't found anything. Why can't I inherit a base class constructor using `using` declaration and add an overload in the derived class? I'm using Visual C++ 2013, the base class constructor is ignored when default-constructing `b`:

```
error C2512: 'B' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

I've dealt with this by re-defining the constructors, but I don't like that. This is just a minimal example, it wouldn't bother me if I had only one base class constructor.

```
struct A
{
    A() : a(10) {}

    int a;
};

struct B : A
{
    using A::A;

    explicit B(int a) { this->a = a; }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

Comment: That is correct code. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979194/what-is-constructor-inheritance.

Comment: @RSahu It would be correct without the other constructor in `B`.

Comment: @0x499602D2, that would be silly -- to not allow `B` to add more constructors just because it inherits constructors from `A`.

Comment: @RSahu `B(int)` is suppressing the creation of a default constructor. He can either remove it or create one himself.

Comment: @0x499602D2, shouldn't `B` inherit the default constructor from `A` after `using A::A;`?

Comment: @RSahu [class.inhctor]/p3: For each non-template constructor in the candidate set of inherited constructors [..], a constructor is implicitly
declared with the same constructor characteristics unless there is a user-declared constructor with the same
signature in the complete class where the using-declaration appears **or the constructor would be a default,
copy, or move constructor for that class**.

Comment: @0x499602D2, Thanks for digging that up. That explains the compiler problem. That would be a perfect answer to the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that default-constructors are not inherited. From [class.inhctor]/p3:

> For each non-template constructor in the candidate set of inherited constructors [..], a constructor is implicitly declared with the same constructor characteristics **unless** there is a user-declared constructor with the same signature in the complete class where the using-declaration appears or **the constructor would be a default, copy, or move constructor for that class**.

You also have a user-declared constructor that suppresses the creation of an implicit default-constructor. Just add a defaulted one to make it work:

```
B() = default;
```